# Counter using Python and RPi does not count consistently

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote a counter code using Python to be used in RPi. I have 2 sensor to do the counting, and the signal is feed into **RPi GPIO**. The counter will count how many times the sensors are triggered.

The code I write for the RPi to count the signal are :

```
    def counteryPlus(channel):
      if GPIO.input(channel):
        countery += 1
      else:
        countery += 0

    def counterzPlus(channel):
      if GPIO.input(channel):
        counterz += 1
      else:
        counterz += 0

    GPIO.add_event_detect(5, GPIO.FALLING, callback=counteryPlus, bouncetime=800)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=counterzPlus, bouncetime=800)
```

When GPIO detect a falling signal at GPIO 5 and 23, it will callback to the function and the function will count in increment.

The **problem** I face is that the counter **does not count consistently sometimes**. Sometimes, countery count but not counterz and vise versa. 
What could be the problem? Is my code does not interrupt properly when the signal is detected? Or could it be a hardware problem?

**Note:**

- What I am using is a photosensor, with a relay. I have connect the GPIO pin to the 'Normally Open' pins of the relay. The photosensor and relay are powered by 24V.
- The counter is display in a GUI using Tkinter.

Comment: You shouldn't expect `GPIO.input(channel)` to be true shortly after the falling edge event was raised.

Comment: Yes Klaus D, that is why the the signal will stay TRUE for about 1 second so that the falling edge event can be properly detected.

Comment: Just to understand better. You really want the 800ms bouncetime? What is the voltage you are feeding the RPi using the relay?

Comment: Tomax, the voltage that are feeding the RPi is 3.3V from the relay. I set the Pin 5 and 23 to have a pull up resistor. And when the sensor is trigger, the relay is on, making pin 5 and 23 to drop to 0V (the ground at RPi). The bouncetime 800ms is about right. The object I am counting have a fix speed around 1 object in 1.3 second.

Comment: You can test the program behavior by setting some other hardware and pulse a signal every 1.3s or so. It may be something to do with the python interaction on the GPIO of the RPi, but I'm really out of my league there.
It maybe also related with the 800ms bouncetime and the 1s relay uptime?

Comment: I tried with 3ms bouncetime, but when my sensor got triggered to TRUE, the counter count non-stop white the sensor is in TRUE state.